# What c# desktop app encoding method encodes to match this encoding

Tags: c#

I'm trying to encode the following string to build a URL

The string:
    `Radio Signal Gabriel Moraes,fernando De Sá`

Encoding that string on this website https://www.urlencoder.org/ gives:
    `Radio%20Signal%20Gabriel%20Moraes%2Cfernando%20De%20S%C3%A1`

When I try to emulate that encoding in C# I can't seem to find a method to do it.

`HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(str);` gives:
    `Radio+Signal+Gabriel+Moraes%2CFernando+de+S%E1`

`Uri.EscapeDataString(str);` gives:
    `Radio+Signal+Gabriel+Moraes%2CFernando+de+S%E1`

`Uri.EscapeUriString(str);` gives:
    `Radio+Signal+Gabriel+Moraes%2CFernando+de+S%E1`

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str);` gives:
    `Radio+Signal+Gabriel+Moraes%2CFernando+de+S%E1`

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str, Encoding.UTF8);`
    `Radio+Signal+Gabriel+Moraes%2CFernando+de+S%E1`

The encoding result returned on the urlencoder website works for the website I'm trying to use it at yet the others don't.

Is there a C# method available in .NET 4.5 Desktop framework that will perform the same encoding as the urlencoder website?

Comment: `+` and `%20` are interchangeable. `+` is a special character for space. `%20` is the ASCII value for the space character.

Comment: How are you measuring your output? Where do those result strings come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you got the results you did but a simple test shows that one of the options you have counted out does *exactly* what you want it to.

The simple test I set up:

```
const string expected = "Radio%20Signal%20Gabriel%20Moraes%2Cfernando%20De%20S%C3%A1";
string input = "Radio Signal Gabriel Moraes,fernando De Sá";
    
var functionDict = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>()
{
    { "HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode", x => HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(x) },
    { "Uri.EscapeDataString", x => Uri.EscapeDataString(x) },
    { "Uri.EscapeUriString", x => Uri.EscapeUriString(x) },
    { "HttpUtility.UrlEncode", x => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x) }
};

Console.WriteLine("Functions that match expected output:");

foreach(var f in functionDict)
{
    string result = f.Value(input);
    
    if(string.Compare(result, expected) == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.Key);
    }
}
```

This gives an output of:

> Functions that match expected output:
>
> Uri.EscapeDataString

So I think maybe you should take another look at [`Uri.EscapeDataString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3LXTfd)

Comment: Good work, but really it should be a close vote. "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

Comment: @spender I was late on the close vote.

Comment: You're absolutely right! There was another UrlEncode in the execution path that I wasn't seeing. EscapeDataString is the one. Thank you!